# Is it possible to check if a switch hit a case?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Let's assume I have a switch statement with a bunch of cases (let's say over 10). Instead of doing something like:

```
switch(str) {
    case "foo":
        //do something
        caseHit = true;
        break;
}

if(caseHit) {
    //do something
}
```

Is it possible to simply check if a switch hit any of the cases? I could add it to the `default` in the switch, so I could do something like this:

```
var caseHit = true;

switch(str) {
    case "foo":
        //do something
        caseHit = true;
        break;

    default:
        caseHit = false;
        break;
}

if(!caseHit) {
    //do something
}
```

But I don't think that's a pretty way of doing it.

EDIT:

Andreas posted a good way of doing it: An object. Here's an example of a better way of doing all of this:

```
const commands = {
    "play": play(),
    "pause": pause()
}

if (typeof commands[str] === "function") {
    commands[str]();
    //and so something else
}
```

Comment: Meh, the `default` case is probably the way I'd do it.

Comment: Is that the only thing you want to do, or does each case perform additional actions beyond `caseHit = true`?

Comment: This is exactly what `default` is for.

Comment: Can't you just set var caseHit = false; Then set it true when a case is set?

Comment: If the indicator is initially true and you change it to false only in the default block then you don't have to do anything in any of the regular blocks.

Comment: I will go with the `default` then. @Ryan Nope, I need to log which command was sent, if it's in one of the cases.

Comment: Why do you think it's not pretty? IMO that's exactly what default cases are for

Comment: If you wanted to reduce the number of extra lines you need, you could just set a variable only in the default and check to see fi the `typeof == undefined`.

Comment: You don't need `break` with `default`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Gotcha. I was hoping you could do something like `var mySwitch = switch(str)...` and then do some magic with `mySwitch`, but that's not the case (hah case.. get it?).

Comment: Why not extract the "do something"  into a method/function and call it in the appropriated cases?

Comment: `const possibleCases = { "foo": function(){}, "bar": function(){} }; if (typeof possibleCases[str] === "function") { possibleCases[str](); } else { /*...*/ }`

Comment: @Fawix I'd have to implement a state machine or something like that. I obviously have functions for each of my cases, so the switch isn't gigantic.

Comment: @Andreas Oh yeah definitely a nice way of doing it. I'll expand my original post to show an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the way to do it, but you can take an optimistic approach:

```
var caseHit = true; //optimistic approach, it will hit a case

switch(str) {
    case "foo":
        //do something
        break;

    default:
        caseHit = false; // if it hit the default it didn't go into any other case's code, unless there's been a waterfall in the switch statement (no break; in any of your cases)
        break;
}

if(!caseHit) {
    //do something
}
```

This way you don't have to `caseHit = true` in every case.

Comment: Optimistic approach. That's a new way of describing it for me! Yeah, I will probably do this.

Answer (score -3):

Uhm, in your case you could just do

```
if (str === 'someCase') //do something
```

I think.

Comment: No, that is definitely not what I want.

Comment: Try to avoid string comparison whenever possible.

Comment: Why not? And why would one avoid string comparison? (btw sorry, I meant to place strict comparison)

Comment: How is this any different than the switch case that has already been implemented? You would have to add this check for every possible case of str.

Comment: Easy... Bugs in string comparisons are hardest to identify, and compared to comparing other types, string comparisons can be expensive.

Comment: So how should I compare strings without comparing strings? 
And `expensiveness` of string comparison is arguable, doesn't have any noticable impact on modern devices.

Comment: @BrandonMiller: The question is *about* comparing strings… I don’t see how you’re going to avoid it.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, I hadn't realized that at the beginning. But my point is still relevant. If you CAN avoid it, then avoid it. If you can't, then that is okay as well.